# How to assign a group name to a group without a group name?

Tags: linux, group

An alternative but less general question would be: How to use `groupmod` based on a group id?

`man groupmod` indicates a group can only be looked up by group name. This is seemingly a problem for groups that only have an id and not a name, see group with id == 999 below:

```
~$ id
uid=1000(brandon) gid=1000(brandon) groups=1000(brandon),999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new group with specific *gid*. You can do this with [`groupadd`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd) and a small `g`:

```
groupadd -g 999 mygroup
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was changed at some point, but -G is not a valid flag on my system. I had to use lowercase -g

```
 groupadd -g 999 mygroup
```